# Como logro que solo el elemento clickeado cambie?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quiero que al darle click al icono que tiene la clase "heart" se cambie su color a azul, de lo contrario a gris, el problema es que funciona, pero se cambia el color de todos los iconos, entiendo por qué pasa pero no solucionarlo, muchas gracias de ante mano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
export function Card({ products }){
const [ColorHeart, setColorHeart] = useState(false);
let HandleClickHeart = () =>{
    setColorHeart(ColorHeart => !ColorHeart);
}

return(
    <>
    <div className="conTitle">
        <p className="title">Productos!</p>
    </div>
    
    <div className='products'>
        <ul className='listProducts'>
            {
                products.map((product, index) =>
                <li key={product.id} className='card'>
                    <div className="corazon">
                        <p>{product.nombre}</p>
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-heart heart" onClick={HandleClickHeart} style={{color: ColorHeart ? 'blue': 'gray'}}></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className='img'>
                        <img src={product.imagen} className='imagenProduct' alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <div className='precio-boton'>
                        <p className='precio'>${product.precio}</p>
                        <button className='botonComprar'>Comprar</button>
                    </div>

                </li>
                )
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: Por favor, el código como texto.

Comment: Listo, disculpa sajsjsj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ocurre porque todos los corazones dependen del mismo estado (colorHeart), solo debes añadir un 'wrapper' en forma de componente a los iconos y que este componente tenga su propio estado independiente de los demás, luego renderizas esos iconos en el componente padre. Por ejemplo un Componente Icono:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { useState } from "react";
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default function Icono(props) {

  const [estadoIcono, setestadoIcono] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => estadoIcono ? setestadoIcono(false) : setestadoIcono(true)
  
  return (
    <div className="icono_contenedor">
      <span>{props.nombrecorazon}</span>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} onClick={handleClick} style={{color: estadoIcono ? 'blue' : 'red'}}></FontAwesomeIcon>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Y luego el componente padre renderiza los iconos, si es necesario recorriendo un array y pasando sus datos como props:

```
import Icono from './components/Icono'

const corazones = ['juan', 'jesus', 'ana', 'micaela', 'francisco', 'lionel']

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {corazones.map((elem, index) => <Icono key={index} nombrecorazon={elem}></Icono> )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Ouhhhh muchas gracias man